# How to perform one final request in scrapy after all requests are done?

Tags: python, scrapy

In the spider I'm bulding, I'm required to login to the website to start performing requests (which is quite simple), and then I go through a loop to perform some thousand requests.

However, in this website in particular, if I do not logout, I get a 10 minute penalty before I can log in again. So I've tried to logout after the loop is done, with a lower priority, like this:

```
def parse_after_login(self, response):
    for item in [long_list]:
        yield scrapy.Request(..., callback=self.parse_result, priority=100)

    # After all requests have been made, perform logout:
    yield scrapy.Request('/logout/', callback=self.parse_logout, priority=0)
```

However, there is no guarantee that the logout request won't be ready before the other requests are done processing, so a premature logout will invalidate the other requests.

I have found no way of performing a new request with the `spider_closed` signal.

How can I perform a new request after all other requests are completed?

Comment: I could be terribly wrong but think `priority=0` might be considered to be a _falsy_ value hence `scrapy` may not consider it's priority. Maybe you could set the priority to `1` instead and tell us if it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `spider_idle` signal, which could send a request when the spider stopped processing everything.

so once you connect a method to the `spider_idle` signal with:

```
self.crawler.signals.connect(self.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
```

you can now use the `self.spider_idle` method to call final tasks once the spider stopped processing everything:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    ...
    self.logged_out = False

    ...
    def spider_idle(self, spider):
        if not self.logged_out:
            self.logged_out = True
            req = Request('someurl', callback=self.parse_logout)
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(req, spider)
```

Comment: Interesting. This method - `self.crawler.engine.crawl()` - could also be called from spider_closed signal?

Comment: no, because at that moment the engine cannot longer process more requests, it is already closed.